# Shell Script to Convert CSV to Text File

Tags: shell, unix

I need to create a shell script that reads a different folder based on today's date and inside the folder contains multiple files and one csv file that will have unique name everyday that is tab delimited. I want to pull this file and resave it as a text file.

Example of file path:

```
data/model/output20190725 (folder contains multiple files, new folder is created everyday)
 -logfile1
 -logfile2
 -part3983isis4838.csv (this csv file will have a new and randomly generated name everyday, the csv file is also tab delimited)
```

I know how to go from a csv file to a text file, but I don't know how to add the logic of the folder name and the csv name changing everyday.

I saw that I could possibly use grep, but I don't know how to navigate to today's date folder and pull the csv and pass to the next argument to make the conversion.

```
grep -l .csv * |
```

Comment: Unclear - "I want to pull this file and resave it as a text file."? If you just want to locate the file, then `find data/model/output20190725 -type f -name "*.csv"` will locate all csv files in the path providing their names on `stdout`. What do you need to do to convert the .csv to text? Just remove the commas and replace with tabs? If so you can do it all in `find`, e.g. `find data/model/output20190725 -type f -name "*.csv" -exec sed -i 's/,/\t/g' '{}' \;`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it's because the first environment does not let me save as a txt, but I was able to save save a csv with tab delimited. The environment that I am sending the file to needs the file as a txt. Also, the date will change. So I don't know how to pull files with yesterday's date.

Comment: You can get the name `yesterdayoutput` (e.g. `20190727output`) with `ydname="$(date -d "yesterday" +'%Y%m%d')output"` I would probably use a helper script (short script called from `find ... -exec helper.sh '{}' \;`) to do the conversion which allows you to remove the `.csv` extension, change all `','` to space (or whatever you need) and then redirect the output to a new file with the `samename.txt`.